# Merging two complex objects in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two data objects converted from JSON. both are quite deeply complex and I'd like to merge them in a similar fashion to how jQuery would merge two objects using extend.

example

JSON 1:

```
{
    ...
    "blah":
    {
        "params":
        {
            "foo":
            {
                "default": "bar",
                "misc": "0",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
    ...
    "blah":
    {
        "params":
        {
            "foo":
            {
                "value": "val",
                "misc": "1",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Merged into

```
{
    ...
    "blah":
    {
        "params":
        {
            "foo":
            {
                "default": "bar",
                "value": "val",
                "misc": "1",
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

What's the best way to approach this with PHP objects.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: OP said "OBJECT" -- not array.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Decode each JSON string into an associative array, merge the results and re-encode

```
$a1 = json_decode( $json1, true );
$a2 = json_decode( $json2, true );

$res = array_merge_recursive( $a1, $a2 );

$resJson = json_encode( $res );
```

**Update:**
If you have a specific merge requirement then you'll need to write your own merging function.
I have written one below which fulfills your requirements as stated in the question.
You may need to tweak it if you have other requirements you haven't mentioned.

```
<?php

$json1 = '
{
    "blah":
    {
        "params":
        {
            "foo":
            {
                "default": "bar",
                "misc": "0"
            }
        },
        "lost":
        {
            "one": "hat",
            "two": "cat"
        }
    }
}';

$json2 = '
{
    "blah":
    {
        "lost": "gone",
        "params":
        {
            "foo":
            {
                "value": "val",
                "misc": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "num_array": [12, 52, 38]
}';


$a1 = json_decode( $json1, true );
$a2 = json_decode( $json2, true );


/*
 * Recursive function that merges two associative arrays
 * - Unlike array_merge_recursive, a differing value for a key
 *   overwrites that key rather than creating an array with both values
 * - A scalar value will overwrite an array value
 */
function my_merge( $arr1, $arr2 )
{
    $keys = array_keys( $arr2 );
    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        if( isset( $arr1[$key] ) 
            && is_array( $arr1[$key] ) 
            && is_array( $arr2[$key] ) 
        ) {
            $arr1[$key] = my_merge( $arr1[$key], $arr2[$key] );
        } else {
            $arr1[$key] = $arr2[$key];
        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}


$a3 = my_merge( $a1, $a2);
$json3 = json_encode( $a3 );
echo( $json3 );

/*
{
    "blah":
    {
        "params":
        {
            "foo":
            {
                "default": "bar",
                "misc":    "1",
                "value":   "val"
            }
        },
        "lost": "gone"
    },
    "num_array": [12,52,38]
}
*/
```

Comment: This nearly does it, but instead of taking overwriting an existing key, it takes the two values and creates an array containing the two. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: I have updated my answer - the merge is purpose built for your requirements

Comment: Sweet, It's pretty close to what I did in the end anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use `array-replace-recursive()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php
It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a code sample please? Link-only answers are not welcome here.

Comment: Hello @JanDvorak There is more than enough code samples under the link. If you feel you need still more than by all means please provide a better answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is simply wrong - the function is for arrays - not for objects. The data in the question contains objects. Of course, you could convert  the objects into arrays and otherwise, but the result will not have the same object structure anymore.

Comment: This is it!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @infinum's link-only answer, `array_replace_recursive()` is the correct, native tool for this task.

I am not sure why the OP accepted @meouw's answer as `array_merge_recursive()` is an inappropriate call and rolling-your-own custom recursive script is unnecessary labor when php already has a single, native call.

With the green tick and so many upvotes on an partially incorrect with a suboptimal bandaid answer, this page is very likely to misinform researchers and represents an unattractive candidate to close future duplicate questions.

The script merely needs to decode the json strings into arrays, call the recursive function, then re-encode the resultant array.

Here is a full demonstration of how to prepare the json strings and employ `array_replace_recursive()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/e9Ife))

```
$json1 = '{"blah":{"params":{"foo":{"default":"bar","misc":"0"}}}}';
$json2 = '{"blah":{"params":{"foo":{"value":"val","misc":"1"}}}}';
echo json_encode(
    array_replace_recursive(
        json_decode($json1, true),
        json_decode($json2, true)
    ),
    JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
);
```

Output:

```
{
    "blah": {
        "params": {
            "foo": {
                "default": "bar",
                "misc": "1",
                "value": "val"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little enhancement on @meouw's code (above) allows merging indexed arrays in objects.

```
$a = '{ "things": ["abc"], "apple":"pear" }';
$b = '{ "things": ["123"] }';

$a1 = json_decode( $a, true );
$b1 = json_decode( $b, true );

echo json_encode(deep_merge($a1,$b1));
// output: {"things":["abc","123"],"apple":"pear"}

function deep_merge( $arr1, $arr2 )
{
    $keys = array_keys( $arr2 );
    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        if (isset($arr1[$key]) && is_numeric($key) ) {
            array_push($arr1,$arr2[$key]);
        }
        else if( isset($arr1[$key]) && is_array($arr1[$key]) && is_array($arr2[$key])) {
            $arr1[$key] = deep_merge( (array)$arr1[$key],(array) $arr2[$key] );
        } else {
            $arr1[$key] = $arr2[$key];
        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}
```

Otherwise, output would be `{"things":["123"],"apple":"pear"}`

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/540c21c5275c5c64a2caae5958eafc87ff3706ec)