# How can I do a join on two JSON objects?

Tags: php, json

It is possible to join on PHP two JSONs on two different columns name (id<->lid)? JSONs looks like that:

```
[{"id":504,"displayname":"Jack","idname":"Work"},{"id":505,"displayname":"Peter","idname":"Home"}]
[{"id":12,"role_id":1800,"prv":2,"lid":504},{"id":20,"role_id":1800,"prv":2,"lid":505}]
```

Ouput should looke like this:

```
[{"id":504,"displayname":"Jack","idname":"Work","id":12,"role_id":1800,"prv":2,"lid":504},{"id":505,"displayname":"Peter","idname":"Home","id":20,"role_id":1800,"prv":2,"lid":505}]
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Your sample output isn't valid JSON. It has duplicate properties `id` inside each object. Do you mean to have _4_ objects in the final array instead of 2?

Comment: @Michael: Actually, JSON does not require keys to be unique. The posted expected result is valid.

Comment: @FelixKling Fair engouh - not _invalid_, but still the first `id` will be overwritten.

Comment: I believe he wants something more like an SQL JOIN between the second array's `lid` and the first array's `id`. I suppose the way to solve multiply defined attributes is to take the id and lid of the second array, and discard the id of the first. Anyway I would solve this with a manual loop but I'm sure someone with more PHP knowledge knows a built-in function. There usually is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you will have keys with the same name in your JSON. In theory, this answer is what you are looking for: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241800/merging-two-complex-objects-in-php)

However, if you require a custom merge algorithm, the following works:

```
$json1 = json_decode($json1String, true);
$json2 = json_decode($json2String, true);

$mergedJson = array();

foreach($json1 as $values)
{
    foreach($json2 as $values2)
    {
        if($values['id'] == $values2['lid'])
        {
            $mergedJson[] = array_merge_recursive($values, $values2);
            break;
        }
    }
}

$finalJsonString = json_encode($mergedJson);
```

This is very basic. I am using the array merge recursive function, but you do not need to use it. You will most likely need to have a bit more code to manually merge the arrays. but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: OK, I changed in 1st JSON column name to join and now both JSON have 'lid' column. When I try this code it was merged but randomly.

Comment: Question 2: I have two very similar JSONs like before and I want to join them but similar to SQL LEFT JOIN.