# merge and overwrite json file where id's match, in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to merge json files, and overwrite when `id`'s match, but it's not overwriting. My PHP is like so:

```
foreach($instagram_array['data'] as $key => $image){
    $id = $image['id'];
    $url    = $image['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
    $date_shot = date('M d, Y', $image['created_time']);
    $likes = $image['likes']['count'];    

$values[id] = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'url' => $url,
    'likes' => $likes,
    'date_shot' => $date_shot,
    $tags = implode(', ', $image['tags']);
);
    };

    $user_array = array_merge($values, $user_array);
    file_put_contents('myfile.json', json_encode($user_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Resulting JSON is like so:

```
{
123_456: {
  id: "123_456",
  url: "photo1.jpg",
  likes: 22,
  date_shot: "Feb 20, 2015",
  tags: "tag1, tag2, tag3"
  },
123_457: {
  id: "123_457",
  url: "//photo2.jpg",
  likes: 20,
  date_shot: "Feb 20, 2015",
  tags: "tag1, tag5"
},...
```

I expected this to use the [$id] as a key, and overwrite the whole sub-array when it matched, but doesn't... It does keep adding more and more files to the file like I want it to, and it also avoids duplicate records as needed, but it just won't update an existing record.

Comment: Post $values array and $user_array

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241800/merging-two-complex-objects-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap the arguments in array_merge like so:

```
$user_array = array_merge($user_array, $values);
```

Comment: omg, so simple but would never had thought to try it... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I think that part of array_merge docs should help you:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

And you have numeric keys. So you can merge it manually or make your keys strings.

Also if you only need to replace elements, not append ones you should take a look on array_replace function